# Get the source file line number of a function

Tags: python, reflection, inspect

Is there a way to accomplish this for any random function?

```
class Class:
    def function(self):
        pass

import inspect
print(inspect.getlineno(Class.function))
```

This just gives:

```
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\inspect.py", line 1479, in getlineno
    return frame.f_lineno
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'f_lineno'
```

Comment: What you really wanted to inspect ? Class or the function ?

Comment: What do you need this for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`inspect.getlineno` expects a frame object.

You should use [`inspect.getsourcelines`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/inspect.html#inspect.getsourcelines) instead:

```
import inspect

class Class:
    def function(self):
        pass

print(inspect.getsourcelines(Class.function))
```

Outputs

```
(['        def function(self):\n', '            pass\n'], 4)
```

It returns a 2-tuple with the actual source code and the definition line number.

```
print(inspect.getsourcelines(Class.function)[1])
# 4
```

Comment: Thanks this helps me a lot.  
And by the way, if  we need to get method first line number by method name, say the class name is "OrderTest"(I need this beacuse I need my unittest to run in test case definition order):  
`def get_line_no(method_name_str):
    return inspect.getsourcelines(getattr(OrderTest, method_name_str))[1]
`

Comment: @MadHatter that is not how "unit" test works. every unit test must be run-able individually, thus called "unit". if you want to do a series of operation, you should write them in one test function with multiple test asserts.

Comment: @InQβ Thanks for the clarification, I understand it's not a typical/standard way to run unit tests in a specific order.

Answer (score 2):

The `Class.function.__code__.co_firstlineno` expression should work faster then running `inspect.getsourcelines(Class.function)` and will also give you a line number.

Comment: very nice. it works

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getsourcelines()`:

```
class Class:
    def function(self):
        pass

import inspect
ins = inspect.getsourcelines(Class.function)
print('Source:',ins[0])
print('Line:',ins[1])
```

Output:

```
Source: ['    def function(self):\n', '        pass\n']
Line: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Following will give the source file line number of the given function.

```
class Class:
    def function(self):
        pass

import inspect
function_definition = inspect.getsourcelines(Class.function)
for output in function_definition:
    print(output)
```